# How to ask for notifications permission on Android using react-native 0.68?

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, permissions

My project is running on react-native 0.68.5 and I can't upgrade it, is there a way to ask for notifications using this react native version?

Right now it's working with previous Android versions, but I want my app to ask for these kind of permissions on newer android versions.

Comment: Take a look at https://reactnative.dev/docs/0.68/permissionsandroid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need past the below line in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS"/>
```

Create a function for request the permission by using below code.

```js
import { Platform,PermissionsAndroid } from 'react-native';

const requestNotificationPermission = async () => {
  if(Platform.OS ==="android"){
    try {
      PermissionsAndroid.check('android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS').then(
        response => {
          if(!response){
            PermissionsAndroid.request('android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS',{
                title: 'Notification',
                message:
                  'App needs access to your notification ' +
                  'so you can get Updates',
                buttonNeutral: 'Ask Me Later',
                buttonNegative: 'Cancel',
                buttonPositive: 'OK',
            })
          }
        }
      ).catch(
        err => {
          console.log("Notification Error=====>",err);
        }
      )
    } catch (err){
      console.log(err);
    }
  }
};
```

Call this **requestNotificationPermission()** function when you want to ask permission for Android Notification permission.